# Click event button on electronjs

Tags: javascript, onclick, electron

I´m traing to add a simple button on a basic electronjs app.

My index,html is:

```
<body>
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>
     We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
     Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
     and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.

    <button type="button" id="btn">Click me!</button>

    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js">
        
    </script>
</body>
```

And the renderer.js:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("btn clicked")   
});
```

but not working.

Any suggestions,
Thanks

Comment: Is the file name ``renderer.js`` or ``render.js``? Are u getting any errors?

Comment: Upps sorry renderer,js

Comment: My falult, from renderer,js console.log not working by default, I have added  --enable-logging in the npm start and now working